# How to create mysql database baseline without data

Tags: mysql, database-administration

How to create a mysql database baseline without data in it so that we could just use the base line to create another instance??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dump of the schema only:

```
mysqldump -d yourdatabase >dumpfile.sql
```

Import this dump into your new database:

```
mysql yournewdatabase <dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: I suppose this gets me the data also right?? Or just the structure??

Comment: Just the structure. The -d indicates that. As alternative you can also use the --no-data (which is just longhand for the -d switch)